# Angular 2 Material 2 Snackbar fails when conditional set inside Firebase event listeners

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-material, firebase-authentication

I'm having an odd problem using the Angular Material 2 library and the Firebase library together.

Here is the code:

```
import {Component, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
import {MdSnackBar} from '@angular/material';
declare const firebase: any;  // declare the firebase global variable so Typescipt doesn't complain

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <button *ngIf="test" (click)="failedAttempt()">Click me</button>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  test = false;
  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef, private snackBar: MdSnackBar) {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      this.test = true;
      this.ref.detectChanges();
    });
  }
  failedAttempt() {
    this.snackBar.open('It didn\'t quite work!', 'Try Again', {duration: 2000});
  }
```

**When I click the button, the Snackbar does not appear.**  No error is thrown, and from what I can tell by inspecting the object, the snackbar does think it is displaying.

If `test` is defaulted to `true` it does appear.

If I add:

`setInterval(()=> this.ref.detectChanges(), 1000)`

before the `firebase.auth()...` event listener, then it works - but I obviously don't want that running constantly.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered on the Angular 2 Gitter channel, but I'm reproducing here for the benefit of others.

From @jordic:

---

The firebase client lib runs outside the zone all async operations. Two ways to solve the problem: Use angularfire2 or wrap the callback from firebase auth state on zone, like this:

```
 import {NgZone} from '@angular/core'

// inject in on service constructor

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => this.zone.run( () => { 
    // this will put firebase call back inside angular zone.
}))
```

---

I couldn't happily use AngularFire2 as the Firebase object needed to be on the window object, but wrapping in the zone worked great.

The official docs for this are here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgZone-class.html

There's also a bunch of further reading, starting here:
https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/22/understanding-zones.html

Hopefully this blog doesn't die any time soon, as there is really too much great info to summarise.